# Set variable from jquery as parameter on SQL Server query on php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql-server, json

i have a php running a sql server query, the results from the query are shown on a table in my html page, but i need to make some filters on the query comming from the client side, as example, the date and a category, but i haven´t realized how to do it and it gives to me this error (at this moment I only tried to put the data from the combobox on the query, because I give up with the date).

[image: Error when I load the html page]

Maybe I could call a default value for the query when the html is loaded (for example, x category  and date = yesterday... but even when i input the info by hand the query doesn´t work.

The date output format of que database is "YYYY-DD-MM HH:MM:SS"

***This is my php:***

```
<?php

function getArraySQL(){
$dsn = "prueba";
$connect = odbc_connect( $dsn, '', '' );
$field_value = $_POST["call"];
$query = "SELECT hist_eqmtlist.unit,
       hist_statusevents.eqmt, 
       hist_exproot.shiftdate, 
       round (sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =1 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end),2) as 'uno',
       round (sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =2 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end),2) as 'dos',
       round (sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =3 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end),2) as 'tres',
       round (sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =4 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end),2) as 'cuatro',
       round (sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =5 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end),2) as 'cinco',
       round (sum(case when hist_statusevents.category =6 then (hist_statusevents.duration/3600) else 0 end),2) as 'seis'
FROM hist_eqmtlist,hist_exproot,hist_statusevents
WHERE hist_exproot.shiftindex = hist_statusevents.shiftindex And hist_statusevents.shiftindex = hist_eqmtlist.shiftindex And hist_statusevents.eqmt = hist_eqmtlist.eqmtid And hist_eqmtlist.unit= '$field_value'
order by hist_exproot.shiftdate,hist_statusevents.eqmt";


if(!$rs = odbc_exec($connect, $query)) die();

$rawdata = array();

$i=0;

while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs))
{
$rawdata[$i] = $row;
$i++;
}
odbc_close( $connect );
return $rawdata;
}
$myarray = getArraySQL();
echo json_encode($myarray);
```

***On the other side, my html is this:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Report Monitor</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src='js/jquery.js'></script>
  <script src='js/bootstrap.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqwidgets/styles/jqx.base.css" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxcore.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxbuttons.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxscrollbar.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxmenu.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxgrid.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxgrid.selection.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxgrid.columnsresize.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxdata.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/demos.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxdatetimeinput.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxcalendar.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxtooltip.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/globalization/globalize.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxlistbox.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jqwidgets/jqxcombobox.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript" name="gridequipment">
    //call the js that bring the data
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var url = "report/eqmq.php";
      // prepare the data
      var source = {
        datatype: "json",
        datafields: [{
          name: 'eqmt'
        }, {
          name: 'shiftdate'
        }, {
          name: 'uno'
        }, {
          name: 'dos'
        }, {
          name: 'tres'
        }, {
          name: 'cuatro'
        }, {
          name: 'cinco'
        }, {
          name: 'seis'
        }],
        id: 'id',
        url: url,
        root: 'data'
      };
      var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);

      $("#datalist").jqxGrid({
        width: '100%',
        source: dataAdapter,
        columnsresize: true,
        columns: [{
          text: 'Equipo',
          dataField: 'eqmt',
          width: '20%'
        }, {
          text: 'Fecha Turno',
          dataField: 'shiftdate',
          width: '25%'
        }, {
          text: 'uno',
          dataField: 'uno',
          width: '9.16%',
          cellsalign: 'left'
        }, {
          text: 'dos',
          dataField: 'dos',
          width: '9.16%',
          cellsalign: 'left'
        }, {
          text: 'tres',
          dataField: 'tres',
          width: '9.16%',
          cellsalign: 'left'
        }, {
          text: 'cuatro',
          dataField: 'cuatro',
          width: '9.16%',
          cellsalign: 'left'
        }, {
          text: 'cinco',
          dataField: 'cinco',
          width: '9.16%',
          cellsalign: 'left'
        }, {
          text: 'seis',
          dataField: 'seis',
          width: '9.16%',
          cellsalign: 'left'
        }]
      });
    });
  </script>



</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <script>
      // The scritp to input the data from combobox into the query on eqmq.php
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var value = $("#callcombo").val();
        $.ajax({
          url: "report/eqmq.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {
            "call": value
          },
          success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
          }
        })

      });
    </script>/
    <!-- / a combobox with the cagories,comming from another query from the same database -->
  </p>
  <section name="combobox">
    <div id='combobox'>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
          var url = "report/eqmlistcat.php";
          var source = {
            datatype: "json",
            datafields: [{
              name: 'unit'
            }],
            url: url,
            async: false
          };
          var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
          $("#callcombo").jqxComboBox({
            selectedIndex: 0,
            source: dataAdapter,
            displayMember: "unit",
            width: 200,
            height: 25
          });
          $("#callcombo").on('select', function(event) {
            if (event.args) {
              var item = event.args.item;
              if (item) {
                var valueelement = $("<div></div>");
                valueelement.text(item.value);
                $("#selectionlog").children().remove();
                $("#selectionlog").append(valueelement);
              }
            }
          });


        });
      </script>
      <div id='callcombo'>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <div id='Datepick'>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // a date picker to input the data on  the query too
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#Dateinput").jqxDateTimeInput({
          width: '200px',
          height: '25px'
        });
        $("#Dateinput").jqxDateTimeInput({
          format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
        });
      });
    </script>
    <p>
      <div id='Dateinput'></div>
    </p>
    <p></p>
    <section name="Equipment List">
      <h3><div id="selectionlog"></div></h3>
      <div id='WidgetTable' style="font-size: 13px; font-family: Verdana; float: center;" class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4">
        <div id="datalist"></div>
      </div>
      <p class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4"></p>
      <p class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4"></p>
      <p class="row col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-4"></p>
    </section>
    <p></p>
</body>

</html>
```